# VBA code to compare first column of muliple spreedsheet in a excel file

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i am new to VBA need help, I have one excel file with multiple spreadsheet.
I want to compare first column of first spreadsheet(Mastersheet) with other spreadsheets first column and highlight the cell in all the sheet which is not present in master sheet.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please do some research, make an attempt and if you have issues then come and ask. If you've already tried to solve this then update your question with what you have tried so far. The macro recorder is usually a great place to start for beginners. However you may be able to get away with just using conditional formatting for your issue if all the files are sitting on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need VBA for this task.
You can use conditional formatting to achieve the end result.

On your Master sheet, make a named range called "MasterList" for the values you have in column A.
Now on another sheet where you want to compare the values, select the while column A and make a new rule for conditional formatting using the formula given below and set the format as per your choice. Make New Rule for each sheet you want to compare with column A of Master Sheet.

```
=AND(A1<>"",COUNTIF(MasterList,A1)=0)
```

Here **MasterList** is the named range you need to create on Master Sheet.